# How do I do a pure Javascript foreach loop and print out the results firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get results from a firebase database and display all the results. Unlike jquery when I can use the appendTo function, I don't know how to get it done with pure javascript.

Here is my script:

```
<div id="resultsContainer"></div>
var fireBaseRef = new Firebase("https:somefirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/results");
fireBaseRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var key = childSnapshot.key();
     // childData will be the actual contents of the child
     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
     var eName = childSnapshot.val().resultname;
     console.log(eName);
     resultsContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="result"></div>';
  });
});
```

As you see I used innerHTML but that gives me just one result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to append HTML with jQuery, that approach will still work fine with Firebase.

But this will work too:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  var eName = childSnapshot.val().resultname;
  resultsContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="result">'+eName+'</div>';
});
```

Note that if you're looking for the equivalent of some specific jQuery construct, it will be a lot easier to help you if you post that jQuery snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I was just missing a "+" in `resultsContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="result">'+eName+'</div>';`